# Quotient of two table cells

Tags: jquery

I have a short question that you may be able to help me with. I'm relatively new to JQuery, but am fairly familiar with HTML, for what it's worth.

I'm trying to find a way to automatically calculate the quotient of two table cells and then display it in a third table cell, preferably rounded off to the first decimal. So something like this:

```
 <table>
     <tr>
          <td class='divisor'>2</td>
          <td class='dividend'>4</td>
          <td class='quotient'>2</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

I don't want this data to be put in by the user, but it would be great if I don't have to do the calculation every time I change the data. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to follow this tutorial (http://wcetdesigns.com/tutorials/2011/11/11/quotient-remainder.html) but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

A basic example. I left a few parts out so you have to think a little bit yourself :-) Let me know if you have any questions

```
$(function(){  //when the DOM is ready

    var divisor = parseInt($('td.divisor').val()); //parse the string to an int
    // get the other value and divide here

    var rounded = Math.round( yourResult * 10 ) / 10; //round the result to one decimal

    $('td.quotient').val(rounded); //set the new value

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var dividend = $("td.dividend").text();
var divisor = $("td.divisor").text();
var quotient = Math.floor(dividend/divisor);
$("td.quotient").text(quotient);
```

working jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/5/

Comment: he asked precision up to the first decimal. using Math.floor removes everything right to the decimal

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var quotient = $('.dividend').html() / $('.divisor').html();
    $('.quotient').html( parseFloat(quotient).toFixed(1) );
});
```

example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/XCjXs/